# Facebook share button is displaying same description on different articles

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I've added the Facebook share button on my page, but I've encountered a problem. When the button is clicked, the picture is displayed correctly and the links are correct too, but the descriptive text under the image is stuck on the same one for the whole website. It's a magazine web in Arabic. I've integrated the feed dialog and it's still the same. [This](http://achabakamagazine.com/new/articles.php?f=1&page=3&categoryID=4) is one article of the page.

Here is the scripts and HTML used:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '847240595353327',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=847240595353327";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#share_button').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Achabaka Magazine',
        link: '<?php echo $actual_link;?>',
        picture: '<?php  echo $pic[0]['big']?>',
        caption: '<?php echo $article['articletitle']?>',
        description: '<?php echo $article['articleintroduction']?>',
        message: ''
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: read about opengraph. add og : description tags appropriately.
http://ogp.me/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fachabakamagazine.com%2Fnew%2Farticles.php%3Ff%3D1%26page%3D3%26categoryID%3D4